# Excel dynamic function

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

I have a simple question and struggling to get the answer.

I have employee list where I want to calculate DeltaDate from today date. I want the output in other column. For example, I have data like this.

```
Name     DOB              DateNow      DeltaDate     
Peter    10.06            17.06        07            
Sam      20.07            17.06        33
```

Ideally I want a desired column when deltadate is 07 then I want "DynamicDelta" to put Yes in all other rows except where DeltaDate is 07

Desired Output:

```
Name     DOB              DateNow      DeltaDate     DynamicDelta
Peter    10.06            17.06        07            No
Sam      20.07            17.06        33            Yes
```

Comment: =if(D2=07,"No","Yes") but the 07 may give a problem, perhaps: if(or(D2=07,D2=7),"No","Yes")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate delta date than DynamicDelta try below formula-

```
=LET(x,C2:C3,y,B2:B3,z,ABS(x-y),r,IF(z=7,"No","Yes"),CHOOSE({1,2},z,r))
```

Only calculate DynamicDelta then try simple `IF()` function like-

```
=IF(D2*1=7,"No","Yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Why `*1`, what's the difference between `=IF(D2*1=7,"No","Yes")` and `=IF(D2=7,"No","Yes")`?

Comment: If `07` is stored as text then need `*1` to convert it to number.